# How to Eliminate Deferred From This Code

Tags: promise, bluebird

It's TypeScript, using BlueBird, and amqplib.  I read somewhere that only losers use "defer", and I don't want to be a loser (for this reason at least).  So i set about trying to rewrite this without - to no avail (just yet):

```
public Request<Rq extends IPublishable, Rs extends IPublishable>(request: Rq): { ackd: Promise<boolean>; response: Promise<Rs> } {
    var ackdPromise: Promise<boolean>;
    var responsePromise: Promise<Rs>;

    var confirmPublish = Promise.promisify(this.ConfirmChannel.publish, this.ConfirmChannel);

    var consumerTag = uuid.v4();
    var responseQueue = Bus.rpcQueueBase + consumerTag;

    var responseDeferred = Promise.defer<Rs>();
    var handleResponse = (msg: IPublishedObj): void => {
        //ack first
        this.ConfirmChannel.ack(msg);
        this.ConfirmChannel.cancel(consumerTag);
        responseDeferred.resolve(Bus.FromSubscription(msg));
    }
    responsePromise = responseDeferred.promise;

    ackdPromise = Promise.resolve(this.ConfirmChannel.assertQueue(responseQueue, { durable: false, exclusive: true, autoDelete: true }))
        .then((okQueueReply) => Promise.resolve(this.ConfirmChannel.consume(responseQueue, handleResponse, { consumerTag: consumerTag })))
        .then((okSubscribeReply) => Promise.resolve(this.ConfirmChannel.assertExchange(Bus.rpcExchange, 'direct', { durable: true, autoDelete: false })))
        .then((okExchangeReply) => confirmPublish(Bus.rpcExchange, request.GetType(), Bus.ToBuffer(request), { type: request.GetType(), replyTo: responseQueue }))
        .then(this.handleAck, this.handleNack)
        .catch((failReason) => {
            console.error(util.format('Error publishing: %s', failReason));
            return false;
        });

    return { ackd: ackdPromise, response: responsePromise };
}
```

I've converted all my similar methods and made a few runs at this, but keep coming up short.  Maybe it's because I'm trying to return two values (the ack promise and the response promise), but really i think it has to do with trying to return a promise for the eventual result of calling the embedded handler - without using a deferred.

Can you (please) do better (or tell me defer is ok)?

Comment: Can you explain in some clear steps or in synchronous code of what you are trying to do? From synchronous code it will be straightforward to translate to promise code

Comment: Can you show us the code for `this.ConfirmChannel.consume`, why does it accept a callback?

Comment: The consume method will read an event off the queue and then pass it to the callback for handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line takes a callback and returns a promise:

```
.then((okQueueReply) => Promise.resolve(this.ConfirmChannel.consume(responseQueue, handleResponse, { consumerTag: consumerTag })))
```

Instead, it is enough to simply return a promise from it, so it becomes:

```
.then((okQueueReply) => Promise.resolve(this.ConfirmChannel.consume(responseQueue, { consumerTag: consumerTag })))
```

While we're there, Promise.resolve is redundant inside `.then` handlers, since they assimilate promises already. Moreover, resolving with  `okSubscribedReply` is only good if it's meaningful, otherwise you know that things went OK since the promise didn'ty reject. So it's better to return the meaningful data.

Since promise chains can branch easily, this would make your code something like:

```
var queueSet = { durable: false, exclusive: true, autoDelete: true };
var tag = { consumerTag: consumerTag };
var channel = Promise.resolve(this.ConfirmChannel.assertQueue(responseQueue, queueSet))
             .then((okQueueReply) => this.ConfirmChannel.consume(responseQueue, tag));

var responsePromise = channel.then((msg) => {
    this.ConfirmChannel.ack(msg); // I don't like this, but ok.
    this.ConfirmChannel.cancel(consumerTag);
    return Bus.FromSubscription(msg);
});
```

So, our `responsePromise` does the same thing, but doesn't require a deferred now, as for our `ackdPromise` we can simply chain it from channel.

```
var exchangeSet = { durable: true, autoDelete: false };
var ackdPromise = channel.then(() => this.ConfirmChannel.assertExchange(Bus.rpcExchange, 'direct', exchangeSet)).then(....);
```

Since you're using `.ConfirmChannel` all the time and not `this` directly, we can utilize `.bind` and do something like:

```
 var assertSettings = { durable: false, exclusive: true, autoDelete: true };
 var p = Promise.bind(this.ConfirmChannel)
                .then(() => this.assertQueue(responseQueue, assertSettings))
                .then(() => this.consume(responseQueue, {consumerTag: consumerTag}));

 var responsePromise = p.then((msg) => {
     this.ack(msg);
     this.cacnel(consumerTag);
     return Bus.FromSubscription(msg);
 });

 var exSet = { durable: true, autoDelete: false };
 var pubSet = { type: request.GetType(), replyTo: responseQueue };
 var ackdPromise = p.then(() => assertExchange(Bus.rpcExchange, 'direct', exSet))
                    .then(() => confirmPublish(Bus.rpcExchange, 
                                               request.GetType(), 
                                               Bus.ToBuffer(request), pubSet))
                    .then(this.handleAck, this.handleNack)
                    .catch(function(err){
                         console.error(util.format('Error publishing: %s', failReason));
                          return false;
                    });
 return { ackd: ackdPromise, response: responsePromise };
```

Comment: I'll need to look at this on a screen bigger than my phone, but two things.  The `ackPromise` ought to be the value returned from the denodeified publish - basically an ack/nack. Second, those Promise. resolves are being used to turn non-bluebird Promises into Bluebird promises.  Does that change things?

Comment: No, Bluebird being a Promises/A+ complaint library will already assimilate those promises.

Comment: Ok, I've finally had a chance to look at this.  I understand now the piece about not putting `Promise.resolve` within a `then` - done.  The next part that confuses me is your `var p = Promise...` code. This is also what tripped me up to begin with.  Your code doesn't specify a callback - a handler - to be called when a message arrives.  It should be the last parameter to `consume`.  How is that connection made in your code?  It doesn't seem to be, it seems to be returning the result of calling consume - which is a promise for a consumerTag.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Quoting the author of bluebird (who may be quoting someone else): `"So when should deferred be used? Well simply, when you have to. You might have to use a deferred object when wrapping a callback API that doesn't follow the standard convention."`

Comment: Hi, sorry, just noticed your comment :S Were you able to get this fixed or are you still struggling with it? @Michael

Comment: I have by and large been able to remove use of "deferred", and out of sheer exposure have a much better general grasp of Promises.  The current implementation is quite different from this.